# System services not available to Activities before onCreate() : ROOM

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, android-room

I have this activity in which I have this callback for when an image is clicked. It was working fine but now I added that if it is clicked then it saves the data on the database. The thing is, now I get the system services not available error and I am not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

This is the activity (I'm only showing the relevant parts of it):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecyclerAdapter.Callback, androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
   private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
   private val movies = mutableListOf<Movie>()
   private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerAdapter
   private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
   private lateinit var mMoviesViewModel: MoviesViewModel

   private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels(
       factoryProducer = { MainViewModelFactory() }
   )

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(binding.root)
       binding.svSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
       //setup progress bar
       progressBar = binding.ProgressBar
       progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

       setObservers()
       initRecyclerView()


   }

private fun initRecyclerView() {
       adapter = RecyclerAdapter(movies)
       binding.rvMovies.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
       binding.rvMovies.adapter = adapter
       adapter.callback = this
   }

//instantiate database for later
   val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
       this,
       MoviesDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
   ).build()

   val dao = db.moviesDao()


   //send details of clicked movie to fragment
   override fun onMovieClicked(movie: Movie) {
       val transaction = supportFragmentManager
       val detailFragment = DetailFragment()
       val data = Bundle()

       //check if movie is already in database

       if(dao.movieExists(movie.id)){
           //send movie's id to fragment
           data.putString("Title", movie.title)
           detailFragment.arguments = data
       } else {

           val title = movie.title
           val image = movie.poster
           val overview = movie.overview
           val language = movie.originalLanguage
           val releaseDate = movie.releaseDate
           val popularity = movie.popularity
           val voteAverage = movie.voteAverage

           //create movie object
           val movie = Movies(id =0, title, image, overview,
               language, popularity, releaseDate, voteAverage
           )

           //add data to db
           mMoviesViewModel.addMovie(movie)

           //send movie's id to fragment
           data.putString("Title", movie.title)
           detailFragment.arguments = data
       }
       //pass data to fragment
       transaction.beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.frag_container, detailFragment)
           .addToBackStack(null)
           .commit()
   }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.app.challengemovieapp.develop, PID: 13142
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app.challengemovieapp.develop/com.app.challengemovieapp.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1960)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
       at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:6143)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$JournalMode.resolve(RoomDatabase.java:663)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:1346)
       at com.app.challengemovieapp.ui.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:129)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
       at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
       at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1219)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3020)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269) 
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1960) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the complete stack trace for your error?

Comment: @CommonsWare I added it now

Comment: The code in your question does not match that stack trace. Can you add whatever is on line 129 of `MainActivity.kt` to your source listing?

Comment: @CommonsWare That is already in the code, it is the part that says     ).build()  when I'm trying to instantiate the room db. I just didn't paste the whole activity code since it's long and not related to this

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to move these lines:

```kotlin
   val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
       this,
       MoviesDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
   ).build()

   val dao = db.moviesDao()
```

Room needs to call methods on `Context` that are not ready at the point when your `MainActivity` is being instantiated. You should not try using Room until after `super.onCreate()` of your `onCreate()` function.

Comment: Oh, I see but how do I use dao's functions that way? If I do that, inside my onMovieClicked I get Unresolved reference: dao

Comment: @satoru: Well, to be honest, your code does not follow modern Android app architecture patterns (repository objects, accessed via viewmodels, that then supply data to your activities/fragments/composables). If you elect to stick with your current architecture, you would need to define those properties as `lateinit var` and populate them in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Oh but I am using viewmodels... I'm just a bit confused because I am using room's viewmodel to get the data in a fragment but I want to check if the data exists before sending the title to my fragment so that my fragment can get it back through room's view model. Maybe i should try to reference room's view model here.. thanks anyway!

Comment: @satoru: "but I am using viewmodels" -- that is good! Ideally, all your I/O should route through the viewmodel, rather than having an activity directly work with a databse. And, ideally, you would have only one `MoviesDatabase` object for your entire app.